# Easily getting function names in F#

Tags: reflection, f#

While searching for an answer, I've found several questions that don't quite match my situation — so I'll ask a new one.

I am writing some FsCheck tests for a data structure, where I want to check about twenty different properties on each copy of the data structure I construct. What I've done so far is to write a predicate for each property, then I've made a list of the predicates and I'll call them each in turn with `List.forall`, like so:

```
module PropertyChecks =
    let ``Tail length plus tree length should equal vector length`` vec =
        treeLength vec.root + Array.length vec.tail = vec.len

    let ``The tail may only be empty iff the vector is empty`` vec =
        (vec.len = 0) = (Array.length vec.tail = 0)

    let ``The tail's length may not exceed tailMax`` vec =
        Array.length vec.tail < tailMax

    let ``If vec.len <= tailMax, all items are in tail and root is empty`` vec =
        (vec.len > tailMax) || (Array.length vec.root = 0)

    // And so on for about 15 more predicates

    let allProperties =
      [
        ``Tail length plus tree length should equal vector length``
        ``The tail may only be empty iff the vector is empty``
        ``The tail's length may not exceed tailMax``
        ``If vec.len <= tailMax, all items are in tail and root is empty``
      ]

    let checkProperties vec =
        allProperties |> List.forall (fun pred -> pred vec)

    // Rest of my code omitted since it's not relevant to the question
```

The problem I'm facing is that I expect that when one property fails because I didn't construct the data structure properly, two or three other properties will fail at the same time. I'd like to get a list of all failing properties, which means that in `checkProperties` I'd like to extract the *name* of the failing predicate. I've seen multiple answers along the lines of "You can't get the `MethodInfo` from an arbitrary F# function that you received as an argument, because you never know whether you got the function itself, or a lambda, or an anonymous function". But here, I not only know that I have real functions, I know what their names are. I could easily copy and paste their names into strings, and make `allProperties` a list of (string,function) tuples. But I'm already feeling not quite happy with having copied-and-pasted once (to put the predicates into that list), and I'd rather not do it twice.

What's a better solution that making a list of (function name, function) tuples? Could I move `allProperties` and `checkProperties` out of the `PropertyChecks` module so that it contains nothing but predicates, and then use reflection to walk that module?

I'm very new to the entire .Net reflection system, so I might well be missing something obvious. Please feel free to point out the obvious if I'm missing it; I won't feel insulted.

Comment: In the absence of a tricky solution with reflection, it wouldn't be too hard to parse this file with a shell script at the level you need

Comment: I read the title and could only think: lambda, lambda, lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hacky bash script that might be easier than reflection:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "let pairs = [|";
cat t.fs | grep let | grep -o "\`\`[^\`]*\`\`" | tr -d \` | awk '{printf "    (\"%s\",``%s``);\n", $0,$0}';
echo "|]"
```

which gives:

```
let pairs = [|
    ("Tail length plus tree length should equal vector length",``Tail length plus tree length should equal vector length``);
    ("The tail may only be empty iff the vector is empty",``The tail may only be empty iff the vector is empty``);
    ("The tail's length may not exceed tailMax",``The tail's length may not exceed tailMax``);
    ("If vec.len <= tailMax, all items are in tail and root is empty",``If vec.len <= tailMax, all items are in tail and root is empty``);
|]
```

Comment: This is still copy-and-paste, but it's an automatic way to ensure that the property pairs get updated if I add new properties, or decide to change the name of an existing property. So although Tomas Petricek's answer was excellent, I've accepted yours since it actually helped me more in my particular situation.

Comment: Well, you could use a makefile to actually make this a separate file and make it get updated in the correct way

Answer (score 5):

The best option for running FsCheck tests is to use FsCheck together with some unit test runner. The test runner takes care of finding all the properties, running them and printing nice error logs when something goes wrong.

The two most common test runners in .NET that both work with FsCheck are xUnit and NUnit and the FsCheck documentation describes how to use them:

- [Using FsCheck with xUnit](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-Xunit)
- [Using FsCheck with NUnit](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/RunningTests.html#Using-FsCheck-NUnit)

In both cases, you mark the properties with the `[<Property>]` attribute and the test runner will use this to find them and run them using FsCheck for you. So you'll need something like:

```
[<Property>]
let ``Tail length plus tree length should equal vector length`` vec =
    treeLength vec.root + Array.length vec.tail = vec.len

[<Property>]
let ``The tail may only be empty iff the vector is empty`` vec =
    (vec.len = 0) = (Array.length vec.tail = 0)

[<Property>]
let ``The tail's length may not exceed tailMax`` vec =
    Array.length vec.tail < tailMax

[<Property>]
let ``If vec.len <= tailMax, all items are in tail and root is empty`` vec =
    (vec.len > tailMax) || (Array.length vec.root = 0)
```

Comment: While this is good advice in general and deserves an upvote, I went with the other answer for my particular case, because the tests look like "Do a bunch of operations on the data structure, then verify that all the properties are still true." So instead of using `[<Property>]` for my tests, I want to write tests like `let vec' = vec |> push "foo" |> insert 3 "bar" |> pop; checkAllProperties vec'`. For that purpose, the "hacky bash script" that John Palmer suggested is more useful. But thanks for the good suggestion; I will certainly use `[<Property>]` in other tests.